# Access Violation when Deallocating Memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I'm currently going through Accelerated C++ and I'm trying to create my version of  in CH11. When trying to deallocate the memory through the destructor I get the read access memory whether I create an empty "Vec" or one using pushback. I'm not really sure what I'm missing.
Thanks for any help.

```
#include "Vec.h"
int main()
{
Vec<int> v;

return 0;
}
```

/////////

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>


using std::max;

/////////////////////////////
template <class T> class Vec {
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;

    //Constructor
    Vec() { create();}
    explicit Vec(size_type n, const T& = T()) {create(n,t);}

    //Copy
    Vec(const Vec& v) {create(v.begin(), v.end());}
    //Assignment
    Vec& operator=(const Vec&);
    //Destructor
    ~Vec() { uncreate();}

    //Indexing
    T& operator[](size_type i) {return data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }



    //Size
    size_type size() const { return avail - data; } 

    //Return member variables
    iterator begin() { return data; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return data; }

    iterator end() { return avail; }
    const_iterator end() const {return avail; }

    //Uncreate
    void clear() { uncreate(); }
    //Check empty
    bool empty() const { return data == avail; }
//////////////////////
private:
    iterator data; //first
    iterator avail; //(one past) last element
    iterator limit; //(one past) allocated memory

    std::allocator<T> alloc; // object for memory allocation

    //allocate and initialize thorugh constructors
    void create();
    void create( size_type, const T&);
    void create(const_iterator, const_iterator);

    //destory 
    void uncreate();


};
////////////////////////////
template <class T> void Vec<T>::create()
{
    data = avail = limit;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(n , 0);
    limit = avail = data + n;
    std::uninitialized_fill(data, limit, val);
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(j - i, 0);
    limit = avail = std::uninitialized_copy(i , j, data);
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::uncreate()
{
    if(data) {
        iterator it = avail;
        while(it != data)
            alloc.destroy(--it);
        alloc.deallocate(data, limit - data);
    }
    data = limit = avail = 0;
}
```

Comment: in `create()` you may be using uninitialized values when doing `data = avail = limit;`  Have you tried gdb?

Comment: In the constructor for `Vec` this: `create(n,t)` is referred to. No such `t` is provided in the parameters. Please update this so it is compilable.

Comment: You are creating an empty `Vec` via `create()` that does not allocate any memory. Does it not surprise you that when calling `uncreate()` in `~Vec()` you get to deallocate memory at all? Your `data` is not `nullptr`. **SB.** must be right.

Comment: Thanks SB. I haven't tried gdb. Thanks for pointing me that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both constructors need to initialize their members in an initializer list prior to usage, (which SB pointed out are being used in `create()` prior to having been assigned determinate values). When the destructor is fired you may well be using a indeterminate pointer value, and sending it to be deallocated.

Change this:

```
Vec() { create();}
explicit Vec(size_type n, const T& = T()) {create(n,t);}
```

To this:

```
Vec() : data(), avail(), limit() { create();}
explicit Vec(size_type n, const T& t = T()) 
    : data(), avail(), limit() {create(n,t);}
```

Comment: No need to call `create` in that first constructor.  Or, since `create()` is itself broken/pointless, an alternative fix might be to change _that_.

Comment: @MooingDuck As-written I concur. If the OP ever adds functionality to the `create()` "family" and wonders why the default ctor isn't picking it up, I suppose she could put it back. I only kept it because it seemed important to the OP. As for changing it and not using an initializer list, I'm no fan of member functions (or any others for that matter) being invoked on objects with indeterminate members. I like them initialized before *anyone* has a crack at them. (but you're certainly right, it is pointless as-written).

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig & SB. I was following through with the book and its source code didn't involve an initializer list, so I didn't think the inital was the issue.

Comment: @Emcy Try and make it a habit for most-all of your variables. (and in some cases, such as references, its not merely a habit; its *required*). It will protect you from mounds of frustration if you always ensure your variables (member or otherwise) have *determinate* values.